# CSS Twentyeleven / Sidebar has to be changed IN the CSS Stylesheet. Sidebar on the left side

Tags: sidebar, theme-twenty-eleven, css

I have to change my wordpress look. The sidebar should be placed on the left side. I was already looking for solutions, but the piece of codes I found didn't fit into mine. I dont know where I have to change it. I know I can change it in the Options, but I need to change it IN the CSS Stylesheet. Thanks for your help !

Twenty Eleven/twentyeleven.44: Stylesheet (style.css)

```
body {
    padding: 0 2em;
}
#page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
#branding hgroup {
   margin: 0 7.6%;
}
#access div {
    margin: 0 7.6%;
}
#primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -26.4% 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 34% 0 7.6%;
    width: 58.4%;
}
#secondary {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 7.6%;
    width: 18.8%;
}


/* Singular */
.singular #primary {
    margin: 0;
}
.singular #content,
.left-sidebar.singular #content {
    margin: 0 7.6%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
.singular .entry-header,
.singular .entry-content,
.singular footer.entry-meta,
.singular #comments-title {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 68.9%;
}


/* Attachments */
.singular .image-attachment .entry-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
.singular .image-attachment .entry-description {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 68.9%;
}


/* Showcase */
.page-template-showcase-php #primary,
.left-sidebar.page-template-showcase-php #primary {
    margin: 0;
}
.page-template-showcase-php #content,
.left-sidebar.page-template-showcase-php #content {
    margin: 0 7.6%;
    width: auto;
}
.page-template-showcase-php section.recent-posts {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 31%;
    width: 69%;
}
.page-template-showcase-php #main .widget-area {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -22.15% 0 0;
    width: 22.15%;
}


/* error404 */
.error404 #primary {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.error404 #primary #content {
    margin: 0 7.6%;
    width: auto;
}


/* Alignment */
.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.625em;
}
.alignright {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.625em;
}
.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Right Content */
.left-sidebar #primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -26.4%;
    width: 100%;
}
.left-sidebar #content {
    margin: 0 7.6% 0 34%;
    width: 58.4%;
}
.left-sidebar #secondary {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 7.6%;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 18.8%;
}
```

Comment: in a child theme? regardless of the theme options? for all index, archive, single, etc pages? would it be ok to add some code to functions.php? if you are looking for a pure CSS solution, this is off-topic for this forum - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: no, he wants a pure css solution, can be maybe moved to stackoverflow if possible

Comment: Yes, move this if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your style.css in the following way:

Find this: `#secondary`

And edit it in this way:

```
#secondary {
    float: left;
    margin: 28px;
    width: 22.8%;
}
```

And then find this: `#primary`

And edit it in this way:

```
#primary {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 -55px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

By doing this, your sidebar will move to the right. You can keep working on these css properties till you get your perfect layout.

Note that this works for TwentyEleven theme.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
#primary {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 -26.4% 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#secondary {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7.6%;
    width: 18.8%; 
}
```

Comment: An explanation of the code would improve this answer.